# Changing the default rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In the rails the default behavior shows the id in the url like

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/1
```

Now to change the url to show me something other than the id, I know I could put this in model

```
def to_param
  name
end
```

And then get something like `http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/mikey`

I am wondering how can achieve a twitter style url. Currently the model name is still showing in the url. Something like this `http://0.0.0.0:3000/mikey` without the model name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get the name of the database column storing your users’ names (let’s say it’s ‘name’).
2. In config/routes.rb add, somewhere above the default route:

   ```
   match 'users/:name', :controller => 'users', :action => 'show'
   ```
3. Now, in users_controller, find def show and change it to:

   ```
   @user = User.find_by_name(params[:name])
   ```
4. Lastly, all the id-based urls pointing to your users need to be updated to reflect the name-based change. Like the one your Users index.html.erb file.

   ```
   link_to @user.name, 'users/#{@user.name}'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Add a route, near the bottom of your routes file (right above your root route!)

```
get '/:id', :to => "users#show", :as => :friendly_user
```

This will act as a fall-through route, so `/anything` that wasn't caught by an earlier route will route to `users#show` and pass an `:id` accordingly. You can then use `friendly_user_path(@user)` to generate links to that user's Twitter-style profile.

Be sure that this is one of the lowest-priority routes, as you wouldn't want a user to be able to sign up with a username like "logout" and replace your `/logout` page with their profile!